# clearing doubt over a definition

Tags: graph-theory, discrete-mathematics, algebraic-graph-theory

[image]

Can anybody tell me what is a Zig-Zag product in graph theory? I am getting no idea how this product is done and how edges are defined in the product? I have some links:

http://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/cs359g-lecture-17-the-zig-zag-product/#more-2203

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zig-zag_product

what does [[n]] x [[D]] means here?
Please help in understanding the above product. Specially about the adjacency among edges. I will be really thankful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The description on Wikipedia seems pretty understandable to me. The original paper could also be helpful - http://dx.doi.org/10.1109%2FSFCS.2000.892006  The bracket notation is a quirk of computer science and should ideally be described in any textbook that uses it.

Comment: The informal description on WP is much better than the formal one, which is hideous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In computer science $[n]$ usually denotes the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $[n]\times [D]$ is the standard Cartesian product. As I see it, the idea behind the Zig-Zag product of graphs is that we want to have something what is product-like, but with small degree.

We start with $D$-regular graph $G$ ($\color{red}{\text{red}}$) and $d$-regular graph $H$ ($\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$). Note, that on the following picture, $H$ is **not** 2-regular, this is wrong, but otherwise the figures would be more complex and less interesting (you can imagine that you see only a part of the graph and there are some more vertices which are not visible).

[image: zigzag01]

As a base we take $|V(G)|$ copies of $H$, so we have $|V(G)|\cdot|V(H)| = |V(G) \times V(H)| $ $= [n]\times [D]$ vertices total.

[image: zigzag02]

Now, we use the fact that $|V(H)| = D$ and that $G$ is $D$-regular, that is, we make the $i$-th vertex of $H_v$ (the copy of $H$ that corresponds to $v \in G$) responsible for the $i$-th edge of vertex $v$. Observe, that the sum of red and blue edges would give you the replacement product of $G$ and $H$.

[image: zigzag03]

Then we add an edge between any two vertices connected by 
$\color{blue}{\text{blue}}\text{-}\color{red}{\text{red}}\text{-}\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ paths, in the following picture 3 such paths have been marked (dotted, dashed, and dot-dashed) in $\color{magenta}{\text{magenta}}$ color.

[image: zigzag04]

And we obtain the following graph:

[image: zigzag05]

Please note, again, that for sake of simplicity and readability we started with $H$ that is **not** regular, hence our resulting graph is not regular too (it should be for regular $H$ as each path starts with $d$ choices for blue edge, then there exists exactly one red edge, and ends with $d$ choices for another blue edge, hence $d^2$-regular).

Also, the article at [French Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Produit_zig-zag_de_graphes) is much more accessible (and has nice pictures too), if you don't speak French, then try [translating it](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Ffr.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FProduit_zig-zag_de_graphes).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$